# osx mavericks keyboard scancodes map to the same characters independent of language map

Tags: macos, layout, keyboard, language-agnostic, scancodes

In my user profile the keyboard types the same characters independent of the keyboard language setting.

Using this four key combinations always produce the same characters:

<kbd>alt-7</kbd> {
<kbd>alt-8</kbd> [
<kbd>alt-9</kbd> ]
<kbd>alt-0</kbd> }

My default Layout is German, so it should be `| { } ≠`

But even on an English and Neo Layout the key combinations produce the same four characters whether in the terminal or in any other native application. Using the on-screen-keyboard overview shows the same behaviour. I can see the Pipe character on the on-screen-keyboard but it types a curly bracket.

The only application that is rendering the correct characters is `Intellij Idea`. I'm suspecting it might be `Java` or `Idea` might just access the `scancodes` directly.

Another user account on the same machine does not show that behaviour (the keyboard renders the expected characters) so it must be something specific to my user profile.

I have done extensive google searching but what I could not find is how the mapping from `scancodes` to characters works in `OSX` on a user profile base.

Since being able to type the '|' character is crucial for me I would greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

I found it: Apparently I did create my own problem a few years ago when trying to use a windows keyboard on my mac to type into a VirtualMachine. Shame on me.

Here is the solution. In my home directory is the file
~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict

With entries like this:

```
{
"\UF729"  = "moveToBeginningOfLine:"; /* pos1 */
"^\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfDocument:"; /* crtl + pos1 */
"$\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfLineAndModifySelection:";
"\UF72b"  = "moveToEndOfLine:"; /* end */
"^\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfDocument:"; /* ctrl + end */
"$\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfLineAndModifySelection:";
"\UF72C"  = "pageUp:";
"\UF72D"  = "pageDown:";
"^~7" = ("insertText:", "|"); /* orig alt 7 */
"^~8" = ("insertText:", "{"); /* orig alt 8 */
"^~9" = ("insertText:", "}"); /* orig alt 9 */
"^\U00DF" = ("insertText:", "\U00BF");
"^+" = ("insertText:", "\U00B1");
"~<" = ("insertText:", "|");
"~7" = ("insertText:", "{");
"~0" = ("insertText:", "}");
"~8" = ("insertText:", "[");
"~9" = ("insertText:", "]");
"~+" = ("insertText:", "~");
"~\U00DF" = ("insertText:", "\U005C");
"~q" = ("insertText:", "@");
"^x" = "cut:";
"^c" = "copy:";
"^v" = "paste:";
}
```